# How to write a reverse line program with recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm learning recursion and am having problems writing a 'simple' program. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!The code compiles with no syntax erros but i still cant use it to serve its purpose.

my *updated* code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class recursion1
{
    static Scanner inFile = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File may not exist");
        }
        reverse(inFile);
        inFile.close();
    }
    public static void reverse(File inFile) throws IOException
    {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        if (inFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            reverse(inFile);
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you having problems with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: First, make sure that you can successfully read a file. Then work on the recursion algorithm.

Comment: I'm stuck on running the program and in general don't really understand how it works. (error message when run : Class names, 'recrusion', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error )

Comment: How are you compiling your source file?

Comment: I'm using the terminal

Comment: A recursive solution to this problem won't use a `while` loop.  A `while` loop is an *iterative* solution, not a *recursive* solution.  In my answer I outline how to do a recursive solution; note that there is no `while` or `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to the purpose of the counter. You decrement it, but you never evaluate it for any sort of logical comparison. I don't think it is unneccessary, you just need to utilize it in a comparison that is used to break the recursive loop. Recursion requires a part that makes a call to the recursive function, and another part that breaks the cycle and begins the process of backing out of the recursive calls.

Comment: yeah i just realized my counter does absolutley nothing... thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Sometimes we need others to look at our own code just to see what is plainly right in front of our noses. I can't tell you how many hours I spent trying to find problems when it was something as simple as a spelling mistake on a variable name. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to write a reversing program in general.  I'm not giving you Java, I'm giving you "pseudocode".

```
function print_reverse(file)
    local_variable line
    line = read_from(file)
    if (we are not at end of file)
        print_reverse(file)
    print line
```

Because `line` is a local variable, you get a new instance of it on each call to `print_reverse()`.  When you read in the whole file, and you want to print the lines in reverse, the lines need to be stored somewhere.  In this recursive function, the lines are stored one at a time, one in each call to `print_reverse()`.

I like to think of recursive functions as "winding" further and further until they hit a limit, then "unwinding" as they come back out.  The limit is called the "basis case".  With any recursive function you need to have a clear idea of what your basis case is.  For `print_reverse()`, the basis case is hitting the end of file on the input file.

After `print_reverse()` hits its basis case, it stops calling itself recursively; it prints a line and then unwinds.  As each recursive call ends, it returns to the previous recursive call, which then in turn prints its line and unwinds again.  This continues until the first call prints its line and terminates, at which point the recursion is finished and all lines have been printed.

So, to summarize:  when "winding" we read a line and save it, the basis case is end of input, and when "unwinding" we print a saved line.  Since unwinding occurs in the exact opposite order of winding, the lines print in reversed order.

If the input file is very large, this recursive solution may use up all the available stack space, in which case the program will crash.  If you wanted to write a file-reversing program that could handle input files of any size, recursion is not going to work.  However, look at how clean and simple this program is.  Some problems are easier to code and understand if you use a recursive solution.

Reversing a file is pretty easy to do iteratively; just use a loop to read each line from the file and keep appending lines to some sort of list, then loop over the list in reverse printing lines.  But other programs are elegantly simple when you write them recursively, and much harder if you don't.  For example, the "Towers of Hanoi" puzzle has a very clean recursive solution.

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/13/hanoi.html